# Move ERC20 tokens from Mac to myetherwallet.com

Tags: accounts

I have the Ethereum Wallet for Mac on my laptop with some ERC20 tokens that I want to send. However I don't have sufficient disk space to synch the nodes to do any transactions it seems.

Can I move them in another way ?
Eg. backup my private key and then use it somewhere else to transfer the tokens ?   Install a wallet on another laptop and do the complete synch and then transfer the tokens ?
What would be the easiest and/or most preferred solution ?

I looked already around but am not able to find the exact solution for me. Maybe because I am also still a newbie :)

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I found it myself and I was closer than I thought.
I renamed the file to one with a json extension because I saw something similar in some post. But now with the correct filename and password I could open it via myetherwallet and just transferred it to another address.  Let's see if it arrives correctly and thus worked :)

Comment: Thanks for following up with your solution. For what it's worth. The tokens have no "location" in the spacial sense. They are spendable from any synced node, which could be your own or could be done via MyEtherWallet or similar. The important thing is the ability to sign a transaction with that key.